# Problema al importar variables en un juego de Blackjack en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en python y en este momento estoy creando un juego de Blackjack para 2-3 jugadores, para ello hice cuatro módulos pero al momento de importar las variables al módulo main me sale un error de importación, a pesar de que he retornado las variables que necesito.

Por otro lado, además de ese error me gustaría saber si presento algún otro error y si me podrían ayudar a corregirlo; me sería de gran utilidad.

Este el código completo:

**main.py**

```
import time

from ganador import ganador_2J
from ganador import ganador_3J
from jugadores import número_jugadores
from jugadores import nombre_jugadores
from turnos import turno

continuar=1

while continuar!=0:
  print("Juego de Blackjack")

  print("")

  if número_jugadores==2:

    print(f" Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.")

    time.sleep(3)

    jugador_1= 0
    jugador_2= 0

    for i in range(número_jugadores):
      print(f"Inicia el Jugador #{i+1}:")

      time.sleep(3)

      if i==0:
        jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])

        print(f"Turno Finalizado. Espera a tu Oponente...\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("")

      else:
        jugador_2 =turno(nombre_jugadores[i])

        print(f"Turno Finalizado.\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("Eligiendo Ganador")

        time.sleep(5)

        print("")

        time.sleep(3)

        ganador_2J(jugador_1,jugador_2,nombre_jugadores)

        continuar=int(input(f"\n¿Desean iniciar una nueva partida?\n1. Si\n0. No\n"))

        del nombre_jugadores[:]

        print("")

  elif(número_jugadores==3):
    print(f"Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.")

    time.sleep(3)

    jugador_1=0
    Jugador_2=0
    jugador_3=0

    for i in range(número_jugadores):
      print(f"Inicia el Jugador numero {i+1}")

      time.sleep(3)

      if i==0:
        jugador_1=int(turno(nombre_jugadores[i]))

        print(f"Turno Finalizado. Espera a tus oponentes...\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("")

      elif(i==1):

        jugador_2=int(turno(nombre_jugadores[i]))

        print(f"Turno finalizado. Espera a tu oponente...\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("")

      else:
        jugador_3=int(turno(nombre_jugadores[i]))

        print(f"Turno finalizado.\n")

        time.sleep(3)

        print("Eligiendo al ganador...")

        time.sleep(5)

        print("")

        time.sleep(3)

        ganador_3J(jugador_1,jugador_2,jugador_3,nombre_jugadores)

        continuar=input(f"\n¿Desean iniciar una nueva partida?\n1. Si\n0. No\n")

        del nombre_jugadores[:]

        print("")
```

**cartas.py**

```
def cartas():

  """ Esta función permite generar el mazo de cartas. """

  valor_cartas=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K","A"]

  palos=["Picas","Corazones","Diamantes","Tréboles"]

  mazo_de_cartas=[]

  for valor in valor_cartas:
    for palo in palos:
      carta=f"{valor} de {palo}"

  mazo_de_cartas.append(carta)

  return(mazo_de_cartas)
```

**ganador.py**

```
import time

def ganador_2J(J1,J2,nombre_jugadores):

  """ Esta función permite determinar al ganador de una partida de Blackjack de dos jugadores. """

  print("")

  time.sleep(3)

  if J1>J2:
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre_jugadores[0]} con un total de {J1} puntos.")

  elif J2>J1:
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre_jugadores[1]} con un total de {J2} puntos.")

  elif J1==J2:
    print(f"Hay un empate, ambos jugadores hicieron {J1} puntos.")

  else:
   print(f"Ambos jugadores perdieron!")


def ganador_3J(J1,J2,J3,nombre_jugadores):

  """ Esta función permite determinar al ganador de una partida de Blackjack de tres jugadores. """

  print("")

  time.sleep(3)

  if J1>J2 and J1>J3:
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre_jugadores[0]} con un total de {J1} puntos.")

  elif J2>J1 and J2>J3:
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre_jugadores[1]} con un total de {J2} puntos.")

  elif J3>J1 and J3>J2:
    print(f"El ganador es{nombre_jugadores[2]} con un total de {J3} puntos.")

  elif J1==J2 and J1!=J3 and J2!=J3:
    print (f"Hay un empate entre {nombre_jugadores[0]} y {nombre_jugadores[1]}, ambos hicieron {J1} puntos.")

  elif J2==J3 and J2!=J1 and J3!=J1:
    print (f"Hay un empate entre {nombre_jugadores[1]} y {nombre_jugadores[2]}, ambos hicieron {J2} puntos.")

  elif J1==J3 and J1!=J2 and J3!=J2:
    print (f"Hay un empate entre {nombre_jugadores[0]} y {nombre_jugadores[2]}, ambos hicieron {J1} puntos.")

  elif J1==J2 and J2==J3:
    print(f"Hay un empate, los tres jugadores hicieron {J1} puntos.")

  else:
    print(f"Los tres jugadores perdieron!")
```

**jugadores.py**

```
def jugadores():

  """ Esta función permite ingresar el número y el nombre de cada uno. """

  número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  nombre_jugadores=[]

  print("")

  for i in range(número_jugadores):

    nombre_jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")

    nombre_jugadores.append(nombre_jugador)

    return(número_jugadores, nombre_jugadores,nombre_jugador)
```

**turnos.py**

```
import random
import time

def turno(mazo_de_cartas,nombre_jugador):
  total=0
  elección=1
  número_carta=1

  cartas_jugador=[]

  print(f"Turno de {nombre_jugador}:")

  while elección!=0 and total<21:
    valor_carta=0

    print (f"\nCarta #{número_carta}:")

    time.sleep(3)

    carta=random.choice(mazo_de_cartas)

    print(f"[carta]")

    if carta[:1] in (10,"J","Q","K"):
      cartas_jugador.append(carta)
      valor_carta=int(10)

    elif carta[:1] in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
      cartas_jugador.append(carta)
      valor_carta=int(carta[:1])  

    elif carta[:1]=="A":

      cartas_jugador.append(carta)

      valor_carta=int(input(f"¿Qué valor quieres que tenga la carta, 1 u 11?:"))

      while valor_carta!=1 or valor_carta!=11:

        if valor_carta==1:
          valor_carta=int(1)

        elif valor_carta==11:
          valor_carta=int(11)  

        else:
          valor_carta=int(input(f"¿Qué valor quieres que tenga la carta, 1 u 11?:"))

  total+=valor_carta

  time.sleep(3)

  if(número_carta>1):
    print(f"Puntaje= {total}\n")

  if(total<21):
    respuesta=2

    while respuesta==2:

      respuesta=int(input(f"¿Qué deseas hacer?:\n1. Pedir otra carta\n2. Mirar tus cartas\n3. Finalizar el turno\n"))

      if(respuesta==1):
        número_carta+=1

      elif(respuesta==2):    
        print(f"Cartas: {cartas_jugador}\n")

        time.sleep(3)

      else:
        elección=0
        return(total)

  elif total==21:
    cartas_jugador.append(carta)

    print(f"Has hecho un Blackjack!")
    return(total)

  else:
    print(f"Has perdido!")
    return(0)
```

Al correr el programa me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jugadores import número_jugadores
ImportError: cannot import name 'número_jugadores' from 'jugadores' (/home/runner/Taller-03/jugadores.py)
```

Edit:

```
#Módulo main

import time

from ganador import ganador_2J
from ganador import ganador_3J
import jugadores
from turnos import turno

continuar=1

while continuar!=0:
  print("Juego de Blackjack")

  print("")

  número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  resultado_tupla=jugadores(número_jugadores)
```

Ahora al correr el programa me sale lo siguiente:

```
Juego de Blackjack

Ingrese el número de jugadores:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    resultado_tupla=jugadores(número_jugadores)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Edit 2:

```
import time

from ganador import ganador_2J
from ganador import ganador_3J
from jugadores import jugadores
from turnos import turno

continuar=1

while continuar!=0:
  print("Juego de Blackjack")

  print("")

  número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  jugadores(número_jugadores)

  if número_jugadores==2:

    print(f" Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.")

    time.sleep(3)

    jugador_1= 0
    jugador_2= 0

    for i in range(número_jugadores):
      print(f"Inicia el jugador {i+1}:")

      time.sleep(3)

      if i==0:
        jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])

#Ahora el problema radica en la parte jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i]), creo que es porque a la función turno le asigné dos argumentos anteriormente
```

Al correr el programa ahora me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Juego de Blackjack

Ingrese el número de jugadores:2

Ingrese el nombre del jugador 1:A
Ingrese el nombre del jugador 2:B
 Hola jugadores, vamos a empezar la partida de Blackjack.
Inicia el jugador 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    jugador_1=turno(nombre_jugadores[i])
NameError: name 'nombre_jugadores' is not defined
```

Comment: ¿`número_jugadores` y `nombre_jugadores` son variables o funciones? Yo solo veo variables que están dentro de `jugadores.py` > `función jugadores`

Comment: @Lleims ambas son variables, he pensado en sacar `número_jugadores` de la `función_jugadores` y colocarla en el `main.py` para correr el código y poner la `función_jugadores` a recibir como argumento  `número_jugadores`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no entiendo muy bien lo que intentas, así que si no és lo siguiente, corrígeme. Por tu comentario entiendo que el número de jugadores prefieres obtenerlo desde el main y una vez tienes este valor mandarlo a la función `jugadores`.

De ser así te recomiendo que simplemente obtengas con un `input` en tu main el número de jugadores y se lo pases cómo parámetro a tu función.

```
# Importamos del archivo jugadores (from jugadores) la función jugadores (import jugadores)
from jugadores import jugadores
#from jugadores import número_jugadores # Estos dos quítalos
#from jugadores import nombre_jugadores

def main():
    # A la altura del código que tu necesites preguntas por la cantidad.
    número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))
    resultado_tupla = jugadores(número_jugadores)
```

Donde ahora tu función jugadores recibirá un parámetro

```
def jugadores(número_jugadores):

  """YA NO - Esta función permite ingresar el número y el nombre de cada uno. """
  """ Esta función permite ingresar el nombre de cada uno de los jugadores. """

  #número_jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  nombre_jugadores=[]

  print("")

  for i in range(número_jugadores):

    nombre_jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")

    nombre_jugadores.append(nombre_jugador)

    return(número_jugadores, nombre_jugadores,nombre_jugador) # Imagino ahora ya la variable número_jugadores ya no hace falta que la devuelvas pues ya la sabes.
```

¡Espero sea esto y si vamos viendo!

PD: Veo tienes acentos en el código, cuidado.

PD2: Por curiosidad, ¿Porque retornas la lista `nombre_jugadores` y también luego `nombre_jugador`?

Comment: Si, eso es exactamente lo que pretendía hacer, retorno `nombre_jugadores` para el módulo `ganador.py` para poder definir al ganador de la partida ya con la lista creada y `nombre_jugador` para que en el módulo `turnos.py` la función me asigne el turno de juego según el nombre de cada jugador.

Comment: Ahora al correr el programa me sale que no puedo llamar a la función, en un momento te muestro

Comment: @jfmejiat A ver que tal ahora :P

Comment: ¿Cómo hago para mostarte lo que tenía en las respuestas?

Comment: Edita tú pregunta y ponlo abajo

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice!

Comment: Pon el import como te he puesto en la respuesta

Comment: Listo, ya te muestro lo que me sale ahora.

Comment: A ver este ya es otro problema, no hay que mezclar, deberías crear una pregunta nueva. Aún así, es porque al llamar a `jugadores(num_jug)` no estás recogiendo el `return`. Si necesitas más ayuda, cierra esta pregunta marcando como respuesta correcta y avísame de que has puesto una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Eso haré, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ya publiqué la pregunta